# Alternate Subset Proof?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Am I allowed to prove

$(A \cap C) \cup (B \cap D) \ \subseteq (A \cup B) \cap (C \cup D)$

by applying the distributive properties of union and intersection to the right side and showing that the left side is embedded in the right side?

I'm wondering if this is an acceptable alternative to showing that an arbitrary element in the left side is in the right side.

Comment: "Allowed" by whom? If you know the distributive law, then sure. A valid proof is a valid proof, and the math police don't care. If your instructor wants a certain type of proof, and has explicitly asked for such a proof, then you have an external constraint.

Comment: I was more wondering if the math police DID care. I didn't know that that was a mathematically valid way to do it. Thanks, though!

Comment: The key is that you need to have proved the distributive law.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments point out, this is a valid proof strategy, provided you've got access to the distributive law -- in the form of (having seen) a proof or that of a premise.